# Crash caused by firebase java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, firebase

My app users have been getting this error for quite sometime. I cannot replicate it myself with physical or virtual devices. It occurs in the on create method. This exception is only thrown for the first firebase instance in the activity.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (Unknown Source:621)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (Unknown Source:47)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (Unknown Source:63)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (Unknown Source:77)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (Unknown Source:73)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (Unknown Source:43)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Unknown Source:19)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Unknown Source:249)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (Unknown Source:98)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Unknown Source:11)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (Unknown Source:282)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState (Unknown Source:29)
  at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp
  at com.pocketchunk.pocketchunk.ui.login.PanelActivity.getClientId (PanelActivity.java:922)
  at com.pocketchunk.pocketchunk.ui.login.PanelActivity.onCreate (PanelActivity.java:175)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Unknown Source:19)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Unknown Source:1)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Unknown Source:3)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (Unknown Source:376)
```

This exception is only thrown by this specific firebase instance even though there is five others in the activity and when I remove it there are no crashes.

Method call at line 175:

getClientId(uid);

Method at line 922:

```
public void getClientId(String uid){
    FirebaseOptions options66222 = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApplicationId(appID)
            .setApiKey(key)
            .setDatabaseUrl(url)
            .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(PanelActivity.this, options66222, "client_id");
    FirebaseApp DB2123 = FirebaseApp.getInstance("client_id");
    FirebaseDatabase DB2123Intance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DB2123);
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(false);

    DatabaseReference DB2123Reference = DB2123Intance.getReference().child("clientid").child(uid);
    // Read from the database
    DB2123Reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            String clientid = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.i("TAG", "Value is: " + clientid);
            final SharedPreferences userPrefs = getSharedPreferences("USER_PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userPrefs.edit();
            editor.putString("whmcsClientid", clientid);
            editor.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
    // Failed to read value
            Log.i("TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It seems it crashes at: `com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState (Unknown Source:29)`. Which line is 922?

Comment: 922 is the firbase databse instance initialization

Comment: So the question is, have you configured everything properly on both sides. Check again configuration setup. Also be sure to call the Firebase initialization in OnCreate method of your Application

Comment: Yes, of course. I have multiple working firebase instances that use the same DB.